# Is my use of a colon correct. If it is correct, is the sentence itself structured okay?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, punctuation, colons

> The traditional narrative is composed of two types of characters: dramatic characters, which are characters that see huge changes to their personality or core beliefs, and static characters, which are characters that have character arcs that stagnate over the course of the story.

Comment: It's fine.  You could also use a semicolon after *beliefs*, but that is optional.

Comment: *Stagnate* is "to become **or** remain stagnant" (M-W). When I read your sentence, I read it as "...characters arcs that *become stagnant* over the course of the story." That of course wouldn't be a static character, so I'm thinking "...character arcs that remain stagnant over the course of the study" would prevent this reading.

Comment: My reading of *become stagnant* was, I think, influenced by seeing "character *arcs*."